# Integrate Countly SDK Web with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sdk, countly-analytics

Has anyone here has experience integrating [Countly SDK Web](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-web) with ReactJS using Typescript?
The example given [here](https://support.count.ly/hc/en-us/articles/360037441932-Web-analytics-JavaScript-) assume people use Javascript to use the SDK. I want to do something like.

```
import { Countly } from 'countly-sdk-web';
```

and use it to hit some API that has been created in Countly when webpage load. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The files is in .tsx extension

Answer (score 0):

you can reach an example on how to integrate Countly Web SDK in a ReactJS project from [here](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-web/tree/master/examples/react).

Again there, a basic example to import Countly would be like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App-WithEffect';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Countly from 'countly-sdk-web';

//Exposing Countly to the DOM as a global variable
//Usecase - Heatmaps
window.Countly = Countly;
Countly.init({
    app_key: 'YOUR_APP_KEY',
    url: 'YOUR_SERVER_URL',
    session_update: 10,
    use_session_cookie: true,
    debug: false,
    require_consent: true,
    namespace: "react-demo",
    inactivity_time: 1,
    offline_mode: false,
    // device_id: "cly-device-demo-id" //Set only if you want dont want to use countly generated device_id
});

//Since Countly is loaded and available, you can use synchronus or asynchronus calls, does not matter
Countly.q.push(['group_features', {
    activity: ["sessions", "events", "views", "location"],
    interaction: ["scrolls", "clicks", "crashes"],
    whereabouts: ["users"]
}]);

if (typeof(localStorage) !== "undefined") {
    var consents = localStorage.getItem("consents");

    if(consents){
        Countly.q.push(['add_consent', JSON.parse(consents)]);
    }
    else{
        var consent = window.confirm("We are going to track you. Do you give your consent ?");
        consents = ["activity", "interaction", "whereabouts"];
        if(consent) {
            Countly.q.push(['add_consent', consents]);
            localStorage.setItem("consents", JSON.stringify(consents));
        }
        else {
            Countly.q.push(['remove_consent', consents]);
            localStorage.removeItem("consents");
        }
    }
}

Countly.q.push(['enableRatingWidgets', {'widgets': ['widget-id-1','widget-id-2']}]);
Countly.q.push(['track_sessions']);
Countly.q.push(['track_scrolls']);
Countly.q.push(['track_clicks']);
Countly.q.push(['track_links']);
Countly.q.push(["track_errors"]);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

You can reach this code from [here](https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-web/blob/master/examples/react/src/index.js)

Comment: I tried embed this inside .tsx file and this error message showed up:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'countly-sdk-web'. '../node_modules/countly-sdk-web/lib/countly.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/countly-sdk-web` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'countly-sdk-web';`  TS7016